# How could I "force" all properties in a struct? To be able to send them to an API?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know how can I force all the properties from this struct to be able to send a POST request to our API?

First of all. I need all those `optional` properties because I make a GET request, I receive all those documents, I process the data, I add the `file` property (which is an object) then I need to send all those documents back to our server with a file added.

We have our `Document`

```
struct Document: Codable {
    let allowedFormats: [String]?
    let processWhereApply: [String]?
    let isRequired: Bool?
    let id, key, title, description: String?
    var file: File?
    // More properties
}
```

But it fails every time, because I'm not sending a string for example. I'm sending an `Optional<String>`

Is there anyway possible I can "force" all those properties to send them back? without like writting 25 lines of `guard let var = var else { return }` ?

I'm sending the POST request with the parameters like this

```
let params = [
            "userId": userId,
            "groupId": groupId,
            "fileDocuments": documents! //sends all properties optional
        ] as [String: Any]
        
        Api().saveDocuments(params: params)
```

Comment: *I need all those optional properties*. I doubt that. Basically declare only those properties as optional which can be `nil`. Your issue looks like a misuse of String Interpolation or `String(describing)`

Comment: @vadian I updated a little my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are sending the data back as Json. In that case just use the Json encode method to convert the struct to Json which can be sent as a POST request. Json encode will deal with the null value issue by setting a corresponding value to the key in your json if the value exists and not creating the key if it doesn't exist.

For example just to get the json:

```
let doc1 = Document(!here you will be initialising variables!) 
// below gives you json as data
let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(doc1)
// if you want your json as string 
let str = String(decoding: json, as: UTF8.self)
```

Here is an example making an alamofire POST request. In the case of alamofire it automatically encodes your struct as long as it conforms to Codable:

```
let doc1 = Document(!here you will be initialising variables!) 
AF.request("https://yoururl.com",method: .post,parameters: doc1, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                print("good response")
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("bad response"
        }
    }
```